# Find a file, convert and store it in the same sub-directory

Tags: linux, bash, sox

I want to convert a **.au** audio dataset to **.wav**. It's stored genre-wise in folders (genres -> rock,jazz,metal,etc). I can find the audio files using the command -

```
find -type f -name '*.au'
```

But I don't know how to pass that list to sox. Also that list has the sub-directory name appended to it at the beginning. How do I remove that?

Comment: How about piping it to `xargs`? Read manual page for `xargs`. If you still have doubts please ask. An example: to check for `message.txt` file under some directory and `cat` it use it like: `find .cache/bower/ -name "message.txt" | xargs cat`

Comment: Getting a single entry from that list is not an issue, although I thank you for this nifty command. I did a string of routines that I am posting as an answer now. If you have a shortcut, I'll be happy to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert; take with a pinch of salt:

Use awk to turn the output of `find` into `sox` commands. Then pass those commands as strings to bash, that will interpret them (as if you gave them a script):

```
find -type f -name '*.au' | awk '{printf "sox [your format options] %s %s\n",$0,$0".wav" }' | bash
```

A more elegant and probably better solution would be, I think, using xargs to turn the output of awk into arguments for sox; something like:

```
find -type f -name '*.au' | awk '{printf "[your format options] %s %s\n",$0,$0".wav" }' | xargs sox
```

But I am not sure of how to use xargs, so... you'll probably have to flesh out the details if you want to use that.

> Also that list has the sub-directory name appended to it at the beginning. How do I remove that?

Why do you want to remove it? You'll need it to reference a file that is in a directory. Aynway, you coud use something like this instead of find:

```
ls Files/relationship/ | grep '\.old'
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty neat. 
What I meant by removing the directory name is that for a file name read as "./metal/metal.00099.au", I would like it to be saved as "metal.00099.wav" in the 'metal' folder, instead of having "./metal/metal.00099.au.wav" in the root folder. Yours falls short in the same respect I think. :)

Comment: I don't think that would happen... but I wouldn't bet my head. It should interpret `./metal/metal.00099.au.wa` as `metal.00099.aw.wav` at `./metal`. BTW, you could use `basename` or `substr` to remove just the extension `.au` too, my AWK only did the bare minimum.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It saves in the correct sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

The folder in question is extracted from the dataset genres.tar.gz which is available from here - http://opihi.cs.uvic.ca/sound/genres.tar.gz

1. I got the list of all files in the directory "genres" using **find** and stored it in a file.

   find -type f -name '*.au' > names.txt
2. This list isn't sorted so I opened it in python, read each line, appended it to a list, sorted it and then saved that list in this file.
3. Using this loop, converted each file to .wav, although I couldn't recover the file name, so used a variable to rename them.

   a=0    #Integer.
   while read line; do sox "$line" "$a".wav; let "a+=1"; done < names.txt

Comment: I don't like this method, as this is just a hack. If someone can come up with something better that can -
1. retain the filename (except the extension)
2. be able to save the converted file in the same sub-directory as its origin.
That'd be very helpful.